# How to make my Makefile check for already compiled files?

Tags: makefile

My goal is to compile all my `*.cpp` files from `Sources` and its subdirectories into the `Objects` directory. They compiles well but when I try to run `make` it recompiles all the files every time.

My makefile goes like this:

```
CXX         := g++
CXXFLAGS    := -IIncludes -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra
LDFLAGS     := -Llib
OBJDIR      := Objects
RMDIR       := rmdir
SDLFLAGS    := -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf

# Switch between Windows and Linux
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
    SRCS := $(shell dir /S /B Sources\*.cpp)
    FixPath = $(subst /,\,$1)
    RM := del /Q
else
    SRCS := $(shell find Sources/ -type f -name '*.cpp')
    FixPath = $1
    RM := rm
endif

EXEC := my_exec.exe
OBJS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
COMP := $(patsubst %.cpp, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(notdir $(SRCS)))

all: $(EXEC)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

%.o: %.cpp | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $(OBJDIR)/$(notdir $@) $<

ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
$(EXEC): $(OBJS) | $(SRCS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(COMP) $(LDFLAGS) -lmingw32 $(SDLFLAGS)
else
$(EXEC): $(OBJS) | $(COMP)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(COMP) $(LDFLAGS) $(SDLFLAGS)
endif

clean:
    $(RM) $(call FixPath, $(COMP))
    $(RMDIR) $(OBJDIR)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(call FixPath, $(EXEC))

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re $(EXEC)
```

I tried using the order-only prerequisites but couldn't get it to detect already updated `.o` files.

Is it possible to achieve this while keeping the compiled files in a different location than their associated `.cpp` files?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is that that is what `make` _does;_ you tell it the dependencies, and it compiles only what needs to be compiled based on that information. Your `Makefile` contains a number of complications which obscure what exactly you want to accomplish. Can you [edit] it down to a [mre], and perhaps also make the title more specific?

Comment: When `make` does not already do what you're asking, it's usually because you've lied to it.  In particular, because you've written a rule whose recipe does not build the rule's target (often because it builds a different file instead).

Answer (score 0):

This rule:

> ```
> %.o: %.cpp | $(OBJDIR)
>     $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $(OBJDIR)/$(notdir $@) $<
> ```

... is badly broken.  This is immediately obvious from the fact that the recipe's only product is `$(OBJDIR)/$(notdir $@)`.  *Every* `make` recipe that intends to build its rule's target should build exactly `$@`, because the name of the rule's target is what that expands to.  If any rule's recipe does not build `$@` (possibly spelled differently) then it is not fulfilling the rule's contract, and a variety of failures can result.  One failure that almost always results is that the rule's recipe runs even when you don't think it should do.

Sometimes you need to adjust the recipe, other times a target or prerequisite pattern.  Your case appears to be of both kinds.  `%.o: %.cpp` says that the rule is for building a target whose name, *including any path segments* matches the name of a source file, but for swapping `.o` for `.cpp`.  That would necessarily be a `.o` file in the same directory as the `.cpp` file (which, incidentally, is traditional).  But,

> [your] goal is to compile all [your] *.cpp files from Sources and its subdirectories into the Objects directory

A rule for that task would start more like this:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: Sources/%.cpp | $(OBJDIR)
```

I suggest, however, not making `$(OBJDIR)` a prerequisite of any kind, but rather building it at need in this rule's recipe.  `mkdir -p` will do that without need for any explicit conditional logic, including when the current directory is not `$(OBJDIR)`'s immediate parent.

The rule would then be something like:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: Sources/%.cpp
        mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

However, making that change to your makefile will require corresponding adjustments.  In particular, your `$(EXEC)` needs to have the expected `Objects/*.o` as its (regular) prerequisites, and to not have the `Sources/*.o` as prerequisites at all.  That's basically what you have in your `COMP` variable, but that variable itself seems a needless complication.  Instead of

> ```
> OBJS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
> COMP := $(patsubst %.cpp, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(notdir $(SRCS)))
> ```

I would work with just

```
OBJS := $(patsubst Sources/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
```

(Linux version; Windows analog left as an exercise.)

Then your rule for `$(EXEC)` has *only* the `$(OBJS)` as any kind of prerequisite, and its recipe refers to them via automatic variable `$^`.  Something like this:

```
$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(SDLFLAGS)
```

Incidentally, I'm not sure whether you really need to link `-lmingw32` explicitly on Windows, but if you do, then it would be more conventional to twiddle that into your `LDFLAGS` variable when appropriate than to have variant versions of the whole rule.

Comment: John I think you're not correct in your statements about order-only prerequisites.  You do in fact want to use them here and you DON'T want to use normal prerequisites.  Having a directory as a normal prerequisite is almost always wrong because the time last modified for a directory is upated any time any new file is created, a file is deleted, or a file is renamed.  That means that your .o files will almost always be out of date with respect to the directory.

Comment: @MadScientist, I agree that this is a bit sticky, but you need it to be a prerequisite at all only if the directory may need to be created under `make`'s control. That's never going to happen unless it is either explicitly specified as a goal target or it is an ordinary prerequisite of some other target that needs to be built.

Comment: It might be better to drop it as a prerequisite altogether, and instead add a `mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)` at the begining of the pattern rule's recipe.  In fact, I am going to add that recommendation to this answer.

Comment: That is not correct.  An order-only prerequisite will be created if it doesn't exist, before its target is invoked.  That's what "order-only" means; it means the prerequisite is handled in order from the target, but it is not considered when deciding if the target needs to be updated (that is, the modification time of that prereqeuisite is not considered when deciding if the target needs to be rebuilt).

Comment: However I do agree with you that a better/simpler method is to add `mkdir -p` to the recipe.  That's what I always use in my makefiles; I rarely/never use order-only prerequisites.

Comment: @MadScientist, damn.  I *always* get that confused.  Apparently, consulting the manual on this point does not help me.  Updating again...